# How to attach file using Lightning Revisited for v37

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, aura

I am attempting to implement a file upload in lightning using API version 37 and this solution:

[How to attach file using Lightning for Salesforce1?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/how-to-attach-file-using-lightning-for-salesforce1)

That solution unfortunately makes a call to [$A.run which has been deprecated](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_get_callback.htm).

I have tried enqueuing the action without a wrapper as follows.

OLD:

```
$A.run(function() {
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
});
```

NEW:

```
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

However, the upload does not start immediately.  In fact, if I do nothing after clicking submit, then the upload does not start at all.  I can coax the upload into starting by either resizing the window or enqueueing another action, but this seems like a waste.  I believe this is caused by the [Boxcarred Action](https://jsforce.github.io/blog/posts/20150620-lightning-boxcarred-action-behavior.html) behavior when using $A.enqueueAction.

Has anybody else experienced this and is there a known workaround that forces an action to execute immediately?

Comment: It sounds like a bug, because it should automatically start after a timeout if no other events are queued. Have you contacted support?

Comment: @sfdcfox - I think you might be right, but I'm not totally sure where to report this.  Is there some place that you recomment?  We are an ISV partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `$A.enqueueAction(action);` needs to be made inside an Aura runtime lifecycle. Previously, `$A.run()` would force this. Now, you can use [$A.getCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm).

You step out of the standard Aura lifecycle during things such as setTimeout, event handlers, etc. Using the linked example you can change the code to the following:

```
fr.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
     // Other code here
     self.upload(component, file, fileContents); // this leads to enqueuing of the action
});
```

I've also edited the [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55905/how-to-attach-file-using-lightning-for-salesforce1) you linked to to have this updated code.

Comment: You are right :). I saw $A.getCallback() but didn't think about hooking it to the onload handler.